# Convert list with each element an object of class into json

Tags: python, json, flask

I have a python list where each element in the list is the object of a class Summershum.Model.File:

```
message = [
<File(tar_file:appstream-glib-0.1.5.tar.xz, filename:/appstream-glib-0.1.5/config.guess, sha256:4a86808b907403ad6801c0661a4524dfa07c0b898a2cef6e7fa0cf82a09b9c53)>, 
<File(tar_file:totem-3.12.1.tar.xz, filename:/totem-3.12.1/build-aux/config.guess, sha256:4a86808b907403ad6801c0661a4524dfa07c0b898a2cef6e7fa0cf82a09b9c53)>,
<File(tar_file:gvfs-1.20.2.tar.xz, filename:/gvfs-1.20.2/config.guess, sha256:4a86808b907403ad6801c0661a4524dfa07c0b898a2cef6e7fa0cf82a09b9c53)>,
<File(tar_file:gnome-software-3.12.2.tar.xz, filename:/gnome-software-3.12.2/config.guess, sha256:4a86808b907403ad6801c0661a4524dfa07c0b898a2cef6e7fa0cf82a09b9c53)>,
<File(tar_file:gnome-packagekit-3.12.2.tar.xz, filename:/gnome-packagekit-3.12.2/config.guess, sha256:4a86808b907403ad6801c0661a4524dfa07c0b898a2cef6e7fa0cf82a09b9c53)>,
<File(tar_file:gnome-color-manager-3.12.2.tar.xz, filename:/gnome-color-manager-3.12.2/config.guess, sha256:4a86808b907403ad6801c0661a4524dfa07c0b898a2cef6e7fa0cf82a09b9c53)>,
<File(tar_file:gnome-chess-3.12.2.tar.xz, filename:/gnome-chess-3.12.2/config.guess, sha256:4a86808b907403ad6801c0661a4524dfa07c0b898a2cef6e7fa0cf82a09b9c53)>,
<File(tar_file:gnome-power-manager-3.12.2.tar.xz, filename:/gnome-power-manager-3.12.2/config.guess, sha256:4a86808b907403ad6801c0661a4524dfa07c0b898a2cef6e7fa0cf82a09b9c53)>,
<File(tar_file:evolution-mapi-3.12.2.tar.xz, filename:/evolution-mapi-3.12.2/config.guess, sha256:4a86808b907403ad6801c0661a4524dfa07c0b898a2cef6e7fa0cf82a09b9c53)>,
<File(tar_file:cockpit-0.7.tar.bz2, filename:/cockpit-0.7/tools/config.guess, sha256:4a86808b907403ad6801c0661a4524dfa07c0b898a2cef6e7fa0cf82a09b9c53)>,
<File(tar_file:xf86-video-freedreno-1.1.0.tar.bz2, filename:/xf86-video-freedreno-1.1.0/config.guess, sha256:4a86808b907403ad6801c0661a4524dfa07c0b898a2cef6e7fa0cf82a09b9c53)>, 
<File(tar_file:elfutils-0.159.tar.bz2, filename:/elfutils-0.159/config/config.guess, sha256:4a86808b907403ad6801c0661a4524dfa07c0b898a2cef6e7fa0cf82a09b9c53)>,
<File(tar_file:ibus-table-1.5.0.20140519.tar.gz, filename:/ibus-table-1.5.0.20140519/config.guess, sha256:4a86808b907403ad6801c0661a4524dfa07c0b898a2cef6e7fa0cf82a09b9c53)>, 
<File(tar_file:fence-agents-4.0.9.tar.xz, filename:/fence-agents-4.0.9/config.guess, sha256:4a86808b907403ad6801c0661a4524dfa07c0b898a2cef6e7fa0cf82a09b9c53)>
]
```

I am trying to convert this list into json and want to pass it to view for displaying (filename, sha1sum).

I was trying to convert the class object using "**json**" method: 
    message = [msg.**json**() for msg in message]
But

```
print message
```

gives me nothing empty list. What is the correct way of doing it?

Comment: So message is not empty before, but is empty after that line? Did you perhaps mean that it becomes a list of empty strings?

Comment: Does this return an empty list [] or a list with [None, None ... ]?

Comment: @RobWatts it do not print anything.

Comment: Nothing? That sounds like there's something else going on here. It would help if you could post at least some of your code.

Comment: @Rahul That helps a little, but I meant your code, not the code of the objects you are using.

Comment: What does `print dir(message[0])` print out?

Comment: It prints http://pastebin.com/dSWkZaaw @RobWatts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the output of `dir(message[0])` that you provided, the error is simple - _there is no `__json__()` method for a `summershum.model.File` object. So I'm guessing that the relevant section of your code looks like this:

```
try:
    ...
    message = [msg.__json__() for msg in message]
    print message
    ...
except Exception:
    # Some code, or just "pass"
```

Because there is no `__json__()` method, you should be getting an `AttributeError`. However, it sounds like you were not seeing an exception, which is why I assume there's a `try...except` block surrounding the code.

With no built-in method to convert the file contents to json, you'll have to use the built-in json module. For example:

```
>>> import json
>>> jsonString = '{"one":"two"}'
>>> jsonObj = json.loads(jsonString)
>>> jsonObj
{u'one': u'two'}
```

You'll need to call `json.loads` and give it the contexts of the file. I'm not sure exactly what you'll need to do that, but based on the available methods I would suggest seeing what the `get` and `tar_file` methods give you.

It's also possible that you're just trying to call `__json__()` too soon - the objects you get from `get` or `tar_file` might have a `__json__()` method.